# How to measure ux for animation effects on mobile

Tags: usability-testing, user-research, mobile-application, animation

My question is if there is a framework or some other way to measure user satisfaction and experience for an touch interaction followed by an animation effect on mobile features.

Take as an example the vertical letter scroll bar in Contacts both on iphone and latest android(4.3). How can you test and rate such an interaction (feedback, speed, proximity to content, simplicity etc)

Answer (score 1):

User test it.

Trying to automate tasks like this is always going to be more work and provide less useful information than building several different versions and then getting a real user to say which they prefer.

Even A/B testing or multi-variant testing will take a lot of work to get the information that 2 or three real people and a bit of time will give you. If you want to be more sure, use more people!

If you have to do it online then build some kind of questionnaire - linked to your prototypes.